# How to get data after waiting for data storing somewhere?

Tags: javascript

I have a table filled like this :

```
setInterval(fillTable,2000);
```

This table is refreshed every 2 seconds. After waiting those 2 seconds I want to get data from this table.

For example, I try this :

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
setTimeout("alert(table.rows.length);",3000);
```

This last line of code should return me the number of rows of the table which is already supposed to be filled ( with setInterval ).

However what I get is :

```
ReferenceError: table is not defined
```

Whereas if I just try :

```
alert(table.rows.length);
```

It's returning 0.

What's wrong ? Is he not aware that the table is filled after 2 seconds ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you're passing a string to setTimeout, it will execute using `Eval()`, so you will lose the reference to the table variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is probably inside a function:

When you call `setTimeout` code you are evaluating gets `this` object as `window`.

so when you access local variable. your code won't work because now it will search for the variable in the global object (`window`).

so put your code inside function and it will work:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert(table.rows.length)
},3000);
```

Comment: Indeed it's inside a function

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert(table.rows.length)
}),3000);
```

Comment: Please don't post 'try this' answers, it's poor quality. Explain what you did and why it should work.

Comment: Well that worked , but I will appreciate an explanation

Comment: the variable table is defined in your method, but when you run a string code, the variable is not found (the code will e runned outside the method)